# Complex submanifolds via Kähler reduction

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, reference-request, dg.differential-geometry, complex-geometry, kahler-manifolds

Let $X$ be a Kähler manifold with an isometric $S^1$-action (which of course complexifies to a $\mathbb C^*$ action). Consider the corresponding Hamiltonian $H$ and let $X_0=H^{-1}(0)/S^1$ be the reduced space, it has a complex analytic structure.

**Question.** Could you please tell me how to prove the following statement (or provide a reference):

*Let $Y\subset X_0$ be a complex analytic subvariety of $X_0$. Consider the subset $Z\subset X$ consisting of all the points in $X$ whose $\mathbb C^*$ orbit or its closure intersects $H^{-1}(0)$ in a point that projects to $Y$. Then $Z$ is complex analytic in $X$.*

Comment: Maybe you can take advantage of results in Heinzner-Migliorini's paper 
"Quotients with respect to holomorphic actions of reductive groups". 
In your case, it seems to me that Theorem 4.4. holds and you get a so called "semistable quotient".
In particular a holomorphic map $\pi$ from $X$ to $X_0 = X//C^*$. So $Z$ is the preimage of
$Y \subset X_0$ hence $Z$ is a complex analytic in $X$ since $\pi$ is holomorphic.